# make ls display current date and time

Tags: ls, date

I'd like ls to display current date and time as a side effect every time I use `ls`. How do I go about changing what a command does?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create an alias which calls `date`, e.g. `alias ls='date;ls'`. Here is an example:

```
$ touch a b c
$ ls
a  b  c
$ alias ls='date;ls'
$ ls
Mon Oct 14 10:37:29 BST 2013
a  b  c
```

Answer (score 1):

Define PS1 variable for your shell, this is the place where you should see whatever you want in your shell.

Example:

```
export PS1="\t [\u@\h \W]\$ "
12:01:58 [user@host ~]$ ls /etc/fstab
/etc/fstab
12:02:00 [user@host ~]$ ls /etc/motd
/etc/motd
```

Comment: an eloborated example would probably be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would like to do this. Maybe you could share what you are really trying to achieve and we could help you find a better solution.

What I personally do is edit my PS1 line. My PS1 line displays a lot of information in the prompt, something like this:
[image: PS1 Line]
As you can see, it displays a wealth of information apart from the Date and Time. In order to show the date and time in your PS1, add `\@` for displaying the time and `\d` for displaying the date.

Answering your question explicitly, you could create an alias in your `.bashrc`. To do this, add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='date && ls'
```

You stated that you don't want to change how a command works. While here it may seem like the opposite, but you must understand how aliases work in order to appreciate the fact that this does not really change the `ls` command. If you do execute ls from within a script, the command is invoked in a subshell which will prevent the parent shell from enforcing your alias rules on it. Hence, no scripts calling `ls` will break because the output format changed.

EDIT: Since some others may be interested in the PS1 line itself, you can find the relevant details [here](http://ix.io/8ta). Beware, it is quite large and if you have directories that have thousands of files, there will be a noticeable lag in the performance of the shell.

Comment: Nice screenshot. Some may appreciate the matching `PS1` value.

Comment: Thanks! It's quite large though. I'll put it up.

Comment: @manatwork: Edited post with a link to the PS1 value.

Comment: Now we know what those numbers are. (BTW, I prefer non-zero exit codes like that 130 in red.)

Comment: That's require some conditional logic inside a PS1 line. I'd rather not have that.